# I got a project to make a quiz game, however the points variable keeps getting reset

Tags: java, variables

The newly assigned value of "points" is never used, I have no idea why but it just gets reset back to zero every time. I couldn't debug it or and still don't know how to get it working. I have also tried assigning a temp variable to keep the value but then the temp also just kept getting reset. Help me my due is in a week and I have no idea what to do anymore

```
package com.project;
import java.util.*;
public class Quiz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int temp =0;
        int points = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(1 + " Category1");
        System.out.println(2 + " Category2");
        System.out.println(3 + " Category3");
        System.out.println(4 + " Category4");
        int categoryChoice = input.nextInt();
        switch (categoryChoice) {
            case 1 -> defineCategory1(points);
            case 2 -> defineCategory2(points);
            case 3 -> defineCategory3(points);
            case 4 -> defineCategory4(points);
            default -> System.out.println("Invalid number");
        }
    }

    public static void defineCategory1(int points) {

        String[] cat1Questions = {
                "Cat1Question1", "Cat1Question2", "Cat1Question3", "Cat1Question4"
        };
        shuffleQuestionsCat1(cat1Questions);
        String[][] cat1Answers = {
                {"cat1Q1RightAnswer", "cat1Q1WrongAnswer1", "cat1Q1WrongAnswer2", "cat1Q1WrongAnswer3"},
                {"cat1Q2RightAnswer", "cat1Q2WrongAnswer1", "cat1Q2WrongAnswer2", "cat1Q2WrongAnswer3"},
                {"cat1Q3RightAnswer", "cat1Q3WrongAnswer1", "cat1Q3WrongAnswer2", "cat1Q3WrongAnswer3"},
                {"cat1Q4RightAnswer", "cat1Q4WrongAnswer1", "cat1Q4WrongAnswer2", "cat1Q4WrongAnswer3"}
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < cat1Questions.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(cat1Questions[i]);
            if (i == 0) {
                switch (cat1Questions[i]) {
                    case "Cat1Question1" -> shuffleAnswersCat1Q1(cat1Answers, points);
                    case "Cat1Question2" -> shuffleAnswersCat1Q2(cat1Answers, points);
                    case "Cat1Question3" -> shuffleAnswersCat1Q3(cat1Answers, points);
                    case "Cat1Question4" -> shuffleAnswersCat1Q4(cat1Answers, points);
                }
            }
            if (i == 1) {
                switch (cat1Questions[i]) {
                    case "Cat1Question1" -> shuffleAnswersCat1Q1(cat1Answers, points);
                    case "Cat1Question2" -> shuffleAnswersCat1Q2(cat1Answers, points);
                    case "Cat1Question3" -> shuffleAnswersCat1Q3(cat1Answers, points);
                    case "Cat1Question4" -> shuffleAnswersCat1Q4(cat1Answers, points);
                }
            }
            if (i == 2) {
                switch (cat1Questions[i]) {
                    case "Cat1Question1" -> shuffleAnswersCat1Q1(cat1Answers, points);
                    case "Cat1Question2" -> shuffleAnswersCat1Q2(cat1Answers, points);
                    case "Cat1Question3" -> shuffleAnswersCat1Q3(cat1Answers, points);
                    case "Cat1Question4" -> shuffleAnswersCat1Q4(cat1Answers, points);
                }
            }
            if (i == 3) {
                switch (cat1Questions[i]) {
                    case "Cat1Question1" -> shuffleAnswersCat1Q1(cat1Answers, points);
                    case "Cat1Question2" -> shuffleAnswersCat1Q2(cat1Answers, points);
                    case "Cat1Question3" -> shuffleAnswersCat1Q3(cat1Answers, points);
                    case "Cat1Question4" -> shuffleAnswersCat1Q4(cat1Answers, points);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(points);

    }

    public static void shuffleQuestionsCat1(String[] cat1Questions) {
        List<String> questionsList = Arrays.asList(cat1Questions);
        Collections.shuffle(questionsList);
        questionsList.toArray(cat1Questions);
    }
    
    public static void shuffleAnswersCat1Q1(String[][] cat1Answers, int points) {
        List<String> answersList1 = Arrays.asList(cat1Answers[0]);
        Collections.shuffle(answersList1);
        answersList1.toArray(cat1Answers[0]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cat1Answers[0]));
        checkAnswerCat1Q1(answersList1, points);
    }
    public static void shuffleAnswersCat1Q2(String[][] cat1Answers, int points) {
        List<String> answersList2 = Arrays.asList(cat1Answers[1]);
        Collections.shuffle(answersList2);
        answersList2.toArray(cat1Answers[1]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cat1Answers[1]));
        checkAnswerCat1Q2(answersList2, points);
    }
    public static void shuffleAnswersCat1Q3(String[][] cat1Answers, int points) {
        List<String> answersList3 = Arrays.asList(cat1Answers[2]);
        Collections.shuffle(answersList3);
        answersList3.toArray(cat1Answers[2]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cat1Answers[2]));
        checkAnswerCat1Q3(answersList3, points );
    }
    public static void shuffleAnswersCat1Q4(String[][] cat1Answers, int points) {
        List<String> answersList4 = Arrays.asList(cat1Answers[3]);
        Collections.shuffle(answersList4);
        answersList4.toArray(cat1Answers[3]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cat1Answers[3]));
        checkAnswerCat1Q4(answersList4, points);
    }

    public static void checkAnswerCat1Q1(List answersList1, int points) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int answer = input.nextInt();
        if (answer - 1 == answersList1.indexOf("cat1Q1RightAnswer")) {
            points++;
            System.out.println("right answer");
        } else {
            System.out.println("game over");
            System.out.println(points);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    public static void checkAnswerCat1Q2(List answersList2, int points) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int answer = input.nextInt();
        if (answer - 1 == answersList2.indexOf("cat1Q2RightAnswer")) {
            points++;
            System.out.println("right answer");
        } else {
            System.out.println("game over");
            System.out.println(points);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    public static void checkAnswerCat1Q3(List answersList3, int points) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int answer = input.nextInt();
        if (answer - 1 == answersList3.indexOf("cat1Q3RightAnswer")) {
            points++;
            System.out.println("right answer");
        } else {
            System.out.println("game over");
            System.out.println(points);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    public static void checkAnswerCat1Q4(List answersList4, int points) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int answer = input.nextInt();
        if (answer - 1 == answersList4.indexOf("cat1Q4RightAnswer")) {
            points++;
            System.out.println("right answer");
        } else {
            System.out.println("game over");
            System.out.println(points);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void defineCategory2(int points) {
        String[] cat2Questions = {
                "Cat2Question1", "Cat2Question2", "Cat2Question3", "Cat2Question4"
        };
        shuffleQuestionsCat2(cat2Questions);
        String[][] cat2Answers = {
                {"cat2Q1RightAnswer", "cat2Q1WrongAnswer1", "cat2Q1WrongAnswer2", "cat2Q1WrongAnswer3"},
                {"cat2Q2RightAnswer", "cat2Q2WrongAnswer1", "cat2Q2WrongAnswer2", "cat2Q2WrongAnswer3"},
                {"cat2Q3RightAnswer", "cat2Q3WrongAnswer1", "cat2Q3WrongAnswer2", "cat2Q3WrongAnswer3"},
                {"cat2Q4RightAnswer", "cat2Q4WrongAnswer1", "cat2Q4WrongAnswer2", "cat2Q4WrongAnswer3"}
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < cat2Questions.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(cat2Questions[i]);
            if (i == 0) {
                switch (cat2Questions[i]) {
                    case "Cat2Question1" -> shuffleAnswersCat2Q1(cat2Answers, points);
                    case "Cat2Question2" -> shuffleAnswersCat2Q2(cat2Answers, points);
                    case "Cat2Question3" -> shuffleAnswersCat2Q3(cat2Answers, points);
                    case "Cat2Question4" -> shuffleAnswersCat2Q4(cat2Answers, points);
                }
            }
            if (i == 1) {
                switch (cat2Questions[i]) {
                    case "Cat2Question1" -> shuffleAnswersCat2Q1(cat2Answers, points);
                    case "Cat2Question2" -> shuffleAnswersCat2Q2(cat2Answers, points);
                    case "Cat2Question3" -> shuffleAnswersCat2Q3(cat2Answers, points);
                    case "Cat2Question4" -> shuffleAnswersCat2Q4(cat2Answers, points);
                }
            }
            if (i == 2) {
                switch (cat2Questions[i]) {
                    case "Cat2Question1" -> shuffleAnswersCat2Q1(cat2Answers, points);
                    case "Cat2Question2" -> shuffleAnswersCat2Q2(cat2Answers, points);
                    case "Cat2Question3" -> shuffleAnswersCat2Q3(cat2Answers, points);
                    case "Cat2Question4" -> shuffleAnswersCat2Q4(cat2Answers, points);
                }
            }
            if (i == 3) {
                switch (cat2Questions[i]) {
                    case "Cat2Question1" -> shuffleAnswersCat2Q1(cat2Answers, points);
                    case "Cat2Question2" -> shuffleAnswersCat2Q2(cat2Answers, points);
                    case "Cat2Question3" -> shuffleAnswersCat2Q3(cat2Answers, points);
                    case "Cat2Question4" -> shuffleAnswersCat2Q4(cat2Answers, points);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(points);


    }

    public static void shuffleQuestionsCat2(String[] cat2Questions) {
        List<String> questionsList = Arrays.asList(cat2Questions);
        Collections.shuffle(questionsList);
        questionsList.toArray(cat2Questions);
    }

    public static void shuffleAnswersCat2Q1(String[][] cat2Answers, int points) {
        List<String> answersList1 = Arrays.asList(cat2Answers[0]);
        Collections.shuffle(answersList1);
        answersList1.toArray(cat2Answers[0]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cat2Answers[0]));
        checkAnswerCat2Q1(answersList1, points);
    }
    public static void shuffleAnswersCat2Q2(String[][] cat2Answers, int points) {
        List<String> answersList2 = Arrays.asList(cat2Answers[1]);
        Collections.shuffle(answersList2);
        answersList2.toArray(cat2Answers[1]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cat2Answers[1]));
        checkAnswerCat2Q2(answersList2, points);
    }
    public static void shuffleAnswersCat2Q3(String[][] cat2Answers, int points) {
        List<String> answersList3 = Arrays.asList(cat2Answers[2]);
        Collections.shuffle(answersList3);
        answersList3.toArray(cat2Answers[2]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cat2Answers[2]));
        checkAnswerCat2Q3(answersList3, points);
    }
    public static void shuffleAnswersCat2Q4(String[][] cat2Answers, int points) {
        List<String> answersList4 = Arrays.asList(cat2Answers[3]);
        Collections.shuffle(answersList4);
        answersList4.toArray(cat2Answers[3]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cat2Answers[3]));
        checkAnswerCat2Q4(answersList4, points);
    }

    public static void checkAnswerCat2Q1(List answersList1, int points) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int answer = input.nextInt();
        if (answer - 1 == answersList1.indexOf("cat2Q1RightAnswer")) {
            points++;
            System.out.println("right answer");
        } else {
            System.out.println("game over");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    public static void checkAnswerCat2Q2(List answersList2, int points) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int answer = input.nextInt();
        if (answer - 1 == answersList2.indexOf("cat2Q2RightAnswer")) {
            points++;
            System.out.println("right answer");

        } else {
            System.out.println("game over");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    public static void checkAnswerCat2Q3(List answersList3, int points) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int answer = input.nextInt();
        if (answer - 1 == answersList3.indexOf("cat2Q3RightAnswer")) {
            points++;
            System.out.println("right answer");

        } else {
            System.out.println("game over");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    public static void checkAnswerCat2Q4(List answersList4, int points) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int answer = input.nextInt();
        if (answer - 1 == answersList4.indexOf("cat2Q4RightAnswer")) {
            points++;
            System.out.println("right answer");

        } else {
            System.out.println("game over");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void defineCategory3(int points) {
        String[] cat3Questions = {
                "Cat3Question1", "Cat3Question2", "Cat3Question3", "Cat3Question4"
        };
        shuffleQuestionsCat3(cat3Questions);
        String[][] cat3Answers = {
                {"cat3Q1RightAnswer", "cat3Q1WrongAnswer1", "cat3Q1WrongAnswer2", "cat3Q1WrongAnswer3"},
                {"cat3Q2RightAnswer", "cat3Q2WrongAnswer1", "cat3Q2WrongAnswer2", "cat3Q2WrongAnswer3"},
                {"cat3Q3RightAnswer", "cat3Q3WrongAnswer1", "cat3Q3WrongAnswer2", "cat3Q3WrongAnswer3"},
                {"cat3Q4RightAnswer", "cat3Q4WrongAnswer1", "cat3Q4WrongAnswer2", "cat3Q4WrongAnswer3"}
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < cat3Questions.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(cat3Questions[i]);
            if (i == 0) {
                switch (cat3Questions[i]) {
                    case "Cat3Question1" -> shuffleAnswersCat3Q1(cat3Answers, points);
                    case "Cat3Question2" -> shuffleAnswersCat3Q2(cat3Answers, points);
                    case "Cat3Question3" -> shuffleAnswersCat3Q3(cat3Answers, points);
                    case "Cat3Question4" -> shuffleAnswersCat3Q4(cat3Answers, points);
                }
            }
            if (i == 1) {
                switch (cat3Questions[i]) {
                    case "Cat3Question1" -> shuffleAnswersCat3Q1(cat3Answers, points);
                    case "Cat3Question2" -> shuffleAnswersCat3Q2(cat3Answers, points);
                    case "Cat3Question3" -> shuffleAnswersCat3Q3(cat3Answers, points);
                    case "Cat3Question4" -> shuffleAnswersCat3Q4(cat3Answers, points);
                }
            }
            if (i == 2) {
                switch (cat3Questions[i]) {
                    case "Cat3Question1" -> shuffleAnswersCat3Q1(cat3Answers, points);
                    case "Cat3Question2" -> shuffleAnswersCat3Q2(cat3Answers, points);
                    case "Cat3Question3" -> shuffleAnswersCat3Q3(cat3Answers, points);
                    case "Cat3Question4" -> shuffleAnswersCat3Q4(cat3Answers, points);
                }
            }
            if (i == 3) {
                switch (cat3Questions[i]) {
                    case "Cat3Question1" -> shuffleAnswersCat3Q1(cat3Answers, points);
                    case "Cat3Question2" -> shuffleAnswersCat3Q2(cat3Answers, points);
                    case "Cat3Question3" -> shuffleAnswersCat3Q3(cat3Answers, points);
                    case "Cat3Question4" -> shuffleAnswersCat3Q4(cat3Answers, points);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(points);
    }

    public static void shuffleQuestionsCat3(String[] cat3Questions) {
        List<String> questionsList = Arrays.asList(cat3Questions);
        Collections.shuffle(questionsList);
        questionsList.toArray(cat3Questions);
    }

    public static void shuffleAnswersCat3Q1(String[][] cat3Answers, int points) {
        List<String> answersList1 = Arrays.asList(cat3Answers[0]);
        Collections.shuffle(answersList1);
        answersList1.toArray(cat3Answers[0]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cat3Answers[0]));
        checkAnswerCat3Q1(answersList1, points);
    }
    public static void shuffleAnswersCat3Q2(String[][] cat3Answers, int points) {
        List<String> answersList2 = Arrays.asList(cat3Answers[1]);
        Collections.shuffle(answersList2);
        answersList2.toArray(cat3Answers[1]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cat3Answers[1]));
        checkAnswerCat3Q2(answersList2, points);
    }
    public static void shuffleAnswersCat3Q3(String[][] cat3Answers, int points) {
        List<String> answersList3 = Arrays.asList(cat3Answers[2]);
        Collections.shuffle(answersList3);
        answersList3.toArray(cat3Answers[2]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cat3Answers[2]));
        checkAnswerCat3Q3(answersList3, points);
    }
    public static void shuffleAnswersCat3Q4(String[][] cat3Answers, int points) {
        List<String> answersList4 = Arrays.asList(cat3Answers[3]);
        Collections.shuffle(answersList4);
        answersList4.toArray(cat3Answers[3]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cat3Answers[3]));
        checkAnswerCat3Q4(answersList4, points);
    }

    public static void checkAnswerCat3Q1(List answersList1, int points) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int answer = input.nextInt();
        if (answer - 1 == answersList1.indexOf("cat4Q1RightAnswer")) {
            points++;
            System.out.println("right answer");
        } else {
            System.out.println("game over");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    public static void checkAnswerCat3Q2(List answersList2, int points) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int answer = input.nextInt();
        if (answer - 1 == answersList2.indexOf("cat4Q2RightAnswer")) {
            points++;
            System.out.println("right answer");

        } else {
            System.out.println("game over");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    public static void checkAnswerCat3Q3(List answersList3, int points) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int answer = input.nextInt();
        if (answer - 1 == answersList3.indexOf("cat4Q3RightAnswer")) {
            points++;
            System.out.println("right answer");

        } else {
            System.out.println("game over");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    public static void checkAnswerCat3Q4(List answersList4, int points) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int answer = input.nextInt();
        if (answer - 1 == answersList4.indexOf("cat4Q4RightAnswer")) {
            points++;
            System.out.println("right answer");

        } else {
            System.out.println("game over");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void defineCategory4(int points) {
        String[] cat4Questions = {
                "Cat4Question1", "Cat4Question2", "Cat4Question3", "Cat4Question4"
        };
        shuffleQuestionsCat4(cat4Questions);
        String[][] cat4Answers = {
                {"cat4Q1RightAnswer", "cat4Q1WrongAnswer1", "cat4Q1WrongAnswer2", "cat4Q1WrongAnswer3"},
                {"cat4Q2RightAnswer", "cat4Q2WrongAnswer1", "cat4Q2WrongAnswer2", "cat4Q2WrongAnswer3"},
                {"cat4Q3RightAnswer", "cat4Q3WrongAnswer1", "cat4Q3WrongAnswer2", "cat4Q3WrongAnswer3"},
                {"cat4Q4RightAnswer", "cat4Q4WrongAnswer1", "cat4Q4WrongAnswer2", "cat4Q4WrongAnswer3"}
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < cat4Questions.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(cat4Questions[i]);
            if (i == 0) {
                switch (cat4Questions[i]) {
                    case "Cat4Question1" -> shuffleAnswersCat4Q1(cat4Answers, points);
                    case "Cat4Question2" -> shuffleAnswersCat4Q2(cat4Answers, points);
                    case "Cat4Question3" -> shuffleAnswersCat4Q3(cat4Answers, points);
                    case "Cat4Question4" -> shuffleAnswersCat4Q4(cat4Answers, points);
                }
            }
            if (i == 1) {
                switch (cat4Questions[i]) {
                    case "Cat4Question1" -> shuffleAnswersCat4Q1(cat4Answers, points);
                    case "Cat4Question2" -> shuffleAnswersCat4Q2(cat4Answers, points);
                    case "Cat4Question3" -> shuffleAnswersCat4Q3(cat4Answers, points);
                    case "Cat4Question4" -> shuffleAnswersCat4Q4(cat4Answers, points);
                }
            }
            if (i == 2) {
                switch (cat4Questions[i]) {
                    case "Cat4Question1" -> shuffleAnswersCat4Q1(cat4Answers, points);
                    case "Cat4Question2" -> shuffleAnswersCat4Q2(cat4Answers, points);
                    case "Cat4Question3" -> shuffleAnswersCat4Q3(cat4Answers, points);
                    case "Cat4Question4" -> shuffleAnswersCat4Q4(cat4Answers, points);
                }
            }
            if (i == 3) {
                switch (cat4Questions[i]) {
                    case "Cat4Question1" -> shuffleAnswersCat4Q1(cat4Answers, points);
                    case "Cat4Question2" -> shuffleAnswersCat4Q2(cat4Answers, points);
                    case "Cat4Question3" -> shuffleAnswersCat4Q3(cat4Answers, points);
                    case "Cat4Question4" -> shuffleAnswersCat4Q4(cat4Answers, points);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(points);
    }

    public static void shuffleQuestionsCat4(String[] cat4Questions) {
        List<String> questionList = Arrays.asList(cat4Questions);
        Collections.shuffle(questionList);
        questionList.toArray(cat4Questions);

    }

    public static void shuffleAnswersCat4Q1(String[][] cat4Answers, int points) {
        List<String> answersList1 = Arrays.asList(cat4Answers[0]);
        Collections.shuffle(answersList1);
        answersList1.toArray(cat4Answers[0]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cat4Answers[0]));
        checkAnswerCat4Q1(answersList1, points);
    }
    public static void shuffleAnswersCat4Q2(String[][] cat4Answers, int points) {
        List<String> answersList2 = Arrays.asList(cat4Answers[1]);
        Collections.shuffle(answersList2);
        answersList2.toArray(cat4Answers[1]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cat4Answers[1]));
        checkAnswerCat4Q2(answersList2, points);
    }
    public static void shuffleAnswersCat4Q3(String[][] cat4Answers, int points) {
        List<String> answersList3 = Arrays.asList(cat4Answers[2]);
        Collections.shuffle(answersList3);
        answersList3.toArray(cat4Answers[2]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cat4Answers[2]));
        checkAnswerCat4Q3(answersList3, points);
    }
    public static void shuffleAnswersCat4Q4(String[][] cat4Answers, int points) {
        List<String> answersList4 = Arrays.asList(cat4Answers[3]);
        Collections.shuffle(answersList4);
        answersList4.toArray(cat4Answers[3]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cat4Answers[3]));
        checkAnswerCat4Q4(answersList4, points);
    }

    public static void checkAnswerCat4Q1(List answersList1, int points) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int answer = input.nextInt();
        if (answer - 1 == answersList1.indexOf("cat4Q1RightAnswer")) {
            points++;
            System.out.println("right answer");
        } else {
            System.out.println("game over");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    public static void checkAnswerCat4Q2(List answersList2, int points) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int answer = input.nextInt();
        if (answer - 1 == answersList2.indexOf("cat4Q2RightAnswer")) {
            points++;
            System.out.println("right answer");

        } else {
            System.out.println("game over");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    public static void checkAnswerCat4Q3(List answersList3, int points) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int answer = input.nextInt();
        if (answer - 1 == answersList3.indexOf("cat4Q3RightAnswer")) {
            points++;
            System.out.println("right answer");

        } else {
            System.out.println("game over");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    public static void checkAnswerCat4Q4(List answersList4, int points) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int answer = input.nextInt();
        if (answer - 1 == answersList4.indexOf("cat4Q4RightAnswer")) {
            points++;
            System.out.println("right answer");

        } else {
            System.out.println("game over");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend debugging your program and at least narrowing the error down enough to produce a [mre]. This is a lot of code to ask someone to look through for you.

Answer (score 0):

MachkaMan1, welcome! to StackOverflow.  To simplify your example, imagine you have:

```
public static main( String[] args ) {
    int points;
    f1( points );
}

private static f1( int points ) {
    points = 17
}
```

When you run this, the call to `f1` is made by *copying* the value of `points` in `main` to the `points` variable in `f1`.  The assignment in `f1` therefore modifies that local *copy* and so the
`points` in `main` is not changed (and starts out as 0).

To get the desired effect, you have to change the argument to `f1` thus:

```
private static f1( int& points ) {
    points = 17
}
```

In this case, `main` passes a `reference` to `points` rather than a copy, and assigning to a reference is equivalent to assigning to the variable that the reference refers to.